# How to insert values to a table with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, xml-parsing

I am using symfony, to insert an XML into a database. I already made the journey to XML, now I need to learn how I store it in the table, without consultation.

```
foreach ($matchInfo->children() as $matchOfficials) {
  foreach ($matchOfficials->attributes() as $key => $value) {
    $arbitro = 0;
    $row = 0;
    while ($row = $arbitro->$row) {
            $arbitro = new Arbitro();
            $arbitro->setNombre($arbitro['FirstName']);
            $arbitro->setApellido($arbitro['LastName']);
            $arbitro->setUid($arbitro['Uid']);
            $entityManager->persist($arbitro);
    }
    $entityManager->flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: `while ($row = $arbitro->$row) {` what do you try to do in this line?

Comment: indicate where the information should be stored in the table. if it's wrong just say it, do not make fun

Comment: I don't laugh on you, you're trying to use `int` like an object and get from it property which is also `int`. I'm just trying to understand which part of this code works. In general, saving to DB is right, I'm sure that your problem in other code, you have to just debug it.

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? If so show us the error log.